# Windows 10 monitor scaling blurry

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, scaling, high-dpi

## Circumstances

- Windows 10 Version 1709 x64
- One 4K (27") and one 2K (27") monitor
- Nvidia 1050 TI

Feel free to ask for more information, if you need them.

---

## The Problem

Everything works fine if I don't use the Scaling option of Windows 10 (`Settings > System > Display > Scale and layout`). However, if I don't use the scaling function, the content on the 4K monitor is very very small.

If I do use the scaling function as recommended (150% for the 4K monitor, 100% for the 2K one), it looks good in general. However, in some applications (Outlook, IntelliJ, ...) the content on the 2K monitor is veary blurry. While there might be a fix for the programs in specific (even though I wasn't able to do this), I'd like a general fix for this problem.

Furthermore, when I use the 4K monitor scaled by 150%, Windows doesn't seem to be quite able to measure the correct size. That means, if I'm at the top right corner of the 4K monitor, at which a maximized window is open, I don't click at the closing button, but slightly above it. This is not that much of a problem though, I could adapt to it.

---

## What I've tried

- I tried running the programs (I tested it with IntelliJ) with `Override high DPI scaling behaviour` set to `System` and `System (Enhanced)`, while using the recommended Windows scaling options

  - The programs controls are as tiny as if I hadn't scaled the monitor at all
- I tried scaling both monitors by the same factor (125%)

  - The controls on the 2K monitor are terribly huge
  - The controls on the 2K monitor still look a little bit blurry, but not as much as before
- I tried [this](http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/) tool

  - The same effect as with scaling both monitors by the same factor
- I tried setting my 2K monitor as primary monitor

  - The contents on the 2K monitor are blurry
- I (obviously) tried logging out and restarting my computer for each option I tried
- I tried some specific solutions for IntelliJ (which didn't work), but I don't think they're relevant here

Comment: Great question - I have the same issue and came across this post: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/ but it sounds like you've tried everything in there already. The only work around I have is to log out and back in again after I've connected the monitors. This clears up the blurriness.

Comment: It seems like JetBrains fixed their HiDPI problems, which makes the scaled monitor usable, but the problem's still not solved, e.g. windows dialogues are still blurry quite often.

Comment: I have this problem too. This is one of the oldest Windows 10 problems, can't believe it only has 2 upvotes (now 3 with mine). Did you find a solution?

Comment: @stuartm Thet blog says at end "If so, please leave a comment below or reach out @WindowsUI." But I see no way to comment. Does anyone know how to contact them? That do they mean with \@WindowsUI ?

Comment: @David I ended up finding solutions for the applications themselves, i.e. special adjustments for IntelliJ and so on. It seems it's less the fault of Windows and more of the application developers - which makes it only more ridiculous that outlook has (or at least had) this problem.

Comment: @MetaColon actually half of apps that are part of Windows have this problem. Like: Explorer, MMC/Device Manager, Paint, and many more.